# php styling images separately when called dynamically

Tags: php, image, call, styling, dynamically-generated

I have created the function to return the images name and id based on a product search. I want to display all the images but I want each image to have a different styling. I guess there's a way of incrementing the div id but not sure. Here's my function and call:

```
public function getImages($searchterm=""){
$sql = "SELECT id FROM prod_detail 
WHERE prod_detail.int_prod_code LIKE '$searchterm' ORDER BY `id` ASC";

$stmt = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql)or die(mysqli_error($this->connection));
while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($stmt)){

$sql2="SELECT image_name FROM images WHERE image_ref={$result['id']}";
$stmt2 = mysqli_query($this->connection, $sql2)or die(mysqli_error($this->connection));
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($stmt2);

while($result2 = $stmt2->fetch_assoc()){
foreach ($result2 as $key => $value) {
$returns = $this->dir . $value;
}
}
}
return $returns;
}
```

Here's the function call displaying the images

```
foreach($newProd->getAllProductSpec($searchterm) as $item => $val){
echo "<img src='server/php/files/{$val['image_name']}' 
alt='Flying screens' style='float:left;margin:0 30px 20px 0'/>"; ?>  
}
```

Comment: how does the styling change per image? is there a limit to the number of images returned?

Answer (score 0):

```
$count = 0;
foreach($newProd->getAllProductSpec($searchterm) as $item => $val){
    echo "<img src='server/php/files/{$val['image_name']}' class='img-{$count}' alt='Flying screens' style='float:left;margin:0 30px 20px 0'/>"; ?>  
    $count++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then you may add an id for each image tag and apply a style for each of these id within your css file. (eg Same answer as Michael just did with the code)

Answer (score 0):

change your function that displays the images into this:

```
foreach($newProd->getAllProductSpec($searchterm) as $item => $val){
echo "<img src='server/php/files/{$val['image_name']}'
alt='Flying screens' id='img{$item}' style='float:left;margin:0 30px 20px 0'/>"; ?>  
}
```

this way, every image wil have an id of 'img0' img1, img2 etc.

you might also want to change your function a little
the part where it sais:

```
while($result2 = $stmt2->fetch_assoc()){
foreach ($result2 as $key => $value) {
$returns = $this->dir . $value;
}
}
}
return $returns;
```

is wrong because it does not return an array;

replace it with this:

```
$returns = array();    
while($result2 = $stmt2->fetch_assoc()){
foreach ($result2 as $key => $value) {
$returns[] = $this->dir . $value;
}
}
}
return $returns;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have changed my code as above but it only returns 1 image. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, this function: $newProd->getAllProductSpec($searchterm) you use in the display function: it should also return an array

Comment: Yes, sorted it now. Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can add some sort of increment easily into your function call displaying the images:

```
$i=1;

foreach($newProd->getAllProductSpec($searchterm) as $item => $val){
  echo "<img src='server/php/files/{$val['image_name']}' 
  alt='Flying screens' id='image-id-$i' style='float:left;margin:0 30px 20px 0'/>"; 

  $i++; // increment this value each time the for each loop completes
}
```